# How can I get an ID from SVG file using javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm having difficulties in accessing an ID that is inside an SVG file and inside of a `rect` tag, to manipulate the SVG's I'm using the Snap.svg library. In this case I want to get the get the `id="rect252"` in javacript file and change the visibility of this object. For some reason I'm not able to get this ID.

**My HTML:**

```
<svg id="main"></svg>
<button onclick="changeSvg('rect252')">Change</a>
```

**My Javascript:**

*To place an image with Snap library*

```
let m = Snap('#main').image("image.svg", 0, 0, 500, 500)
```

*Function*

```
function changeSvg(id){
    let svgTag = document.getElementById('main')
    svgTag.addEventListener("load", function(){
        let svgDoc = svgTag.contentDocument;
        let getID = svgDoc.getElementById(id);
        
        Snap('#' + getID).attr({
            visibility: 'visible'
        })
    })
}
```

**SVG Structure:**

```
 <g
     id="g327"
     inkscape:label="Top Center"
     transform="translate(-3.3026586,-12.907715)"
     style="display:block">
    <rect
       style="display:inline;fill:#000000"
       id="rect252"
       width="51.396542"
       height="31.275505"
       x="120.8588"
       y="92.630028"
       inkscape:label="Right"
       visibility="hidden" />
  </g>
```

If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it, thanks

Comment: contentDocument is for iFrame

Comment: I'm seeing, but I can't find any solution

Comment: You can't interact with an image. That includes accessing anything within one programmatically.

Comment: The image that I want to interact is a svg that have multiple layers, and I just need to interact with this layers and not directly with the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the id for an svg image.

However, you can if you use an object tag instead.

```
<object id="main" data="image.svg" width="600" height="600" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Then you can use contentDocument to access it. Example.

```
var tux = Snap("#main");
var tuxContent = tux.node.contentDocument;   /// grab the referenced content
```

Comment: I tried to use this solution, but the svg is not placed inside the object tag, do you know what the problem must be?

Comment: Not without being able to see the code. Sure the directory and name is correct ?

Comment: I didn't want to use the data property in the html but define it in javascript with Snap, but if I define an image in the data it works correctly.